# Is it possible using a describe group as a function in Rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I want to a example group as a function.

But a function definition in a example group scope occurs an error like this.

```
FUNCTION-NAME is not available on an example group (e.g. a `describe` or `context` block).`...
```

The code like this.

```
describe '...' do
  def func(*args)
    # This example group is nested and contains examples.
    describe '...' do
      ...
    end
  end
  func(*args1)
  func(*args2)
end
```

Is it possible avoiding this error? Or is there any alternative ways?

Comment: This should work. We'll need a [mcve] to tell exactly what's wrong here. Also, it seems that you want to use rspec's [shared examples](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples).

Comment: You should look into shared examples

Comment: It feels to me like you are trying to re-implement [shared examples](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples).

Comment: I did not know shared examples. Thank you and sorry for shortage of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you should be using RSpec's shared examples. Lifted from another answer of mine, below is an example which should be self explanatory and demonstrating various ways of passing *arguments* using a let block.

The shared_examples block at the top is the equivalent of the *method* if you like, and the rest are examples which demonstrate use of that shared_examples block.

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Array, type: :class do
  shared_examples 'an array of hashes' do
    it { expect(array).to be_an_instance_of(Array) }

    it 'each element should be an instance of Hash' do
      array.each { |element| expect(element).to be_an_instance_of(Hash) }
    end
  end

  describe 'with an array of hashes' do
    context 'with predefined array' do
      let(:hash) { Hash.new(name: 'hash', value: 'value') }
      let(:array) { [hash, hash, hash] }

      context 'without using shared examples' do
        it { expect(array).to be_an_instance_of(Array) }

        it 'each element should be an instance of Hash' do
          array.each { |element| expect(element).to be_an_instance_of(Hash) }
        end
      end

      context 'using shared examples' do
        it_should_behave_like 'an array of hashes'
      end
    end

    context 'when passing array to shared example' do
      let(:hash) { Hash.new(name: 'hash', value: 'value') }
      let(:myarray) { [hash, hash, hash] }

      it_should_behave_like 'an array of hashes' do
        let(:array) { myarray }
      end

      context 'with use of before(:each) block' do
        before(:each) do
          @myarray = myarray
        end

        it_should_behave_like 'an array of hashes' do
          let(:array) { @myarray }
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```